# This query contains transformations that cannot be used in DirectQuery

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Invoking the following function in Power Query editor returns the error below:

```
let
    Origem = (x, y) => x * y
in
    Origem
```

Invoked Funtion:

```
This query contains transformations that cannot be used in DirectQuery.
```

[image]

This is the only query I have in this data model so I have no idea why this message..

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a Power BI bug with the new `Composite Model Preview` setting.

If you turn it off, restart Power BI, then copy and paste the old query into a new one, and delete the old one, it should refresh fine.

Reference:

[DirectQuery errors on imported tables. July 2018 Composite Models.](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/DirectQuery-errors-on-imported-tables-July-2018-Composite-Models/idi-p/470669/page/3#comments)

[this query contains transformations that can't be used for directquery](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/this-query-contains-transformations-that-can-t-be-used-for/td-p/483131)